# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'employee_signature' cannot be null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am facing an issue with submitting signature data to the database in my Laravel application. The peculiar thing is that this problem only occurs when I have authentication enabled. When I remove the authentication middleware from the routes, everything works as expected.

Here is the relevant Blade code for the signature inputs:

```php
<div class="row">
    <!-- Employee Signature -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="employee_signature">Employee Signature</label>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <canvas id="employee_signature" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="clear_employee_signature" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Clear</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="employee_signature_data" name="employee_signature">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Customer Signature -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customer_signature">Customer Signature</label>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <canvas id="customer_signature" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="clear_customer_signature" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Clear</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="customer_signature_data" name="customer_signature">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image_draw">Damage</label>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <canvas id="image_draw" style="width: 100%; height: 470px;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="clear_image_draw" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Clear</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="image_draw_data" name="image_draw">
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var employeeSignatureCanvas = document.getElementById('employee_signature');
    var customerSignatureCanvas = document.getElementById('customer_signature');
    var imageDrawCanvas = document.getElementById('image_draw'); 

    [employeeSignatureCanvas, customerSignatureCanvas, imageDrawCanvas].forEach(canvas => {
        canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
    });

    var employeeSignaturePad = new SignaturePad(employeeSignatureCanvas, {penColor: 'red', minWidth: 1, maxWidth: 1});
    var customerSignaturePad = new SignaturePad(customerSignatureCanvas, {penColor: 'red', minWidth: 1, maxWidth: 1});
    var imageDrawPad = new SignaturePad(imageDrawCanvas, {penColor: 'red', minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 10});

    document.getElementById('clear_employee_signature').addEventListener('click', function () {
        employeeSignaturePad.clear();
    });
    document.getElementById('clear_customer_signature').addEventListener('click', function () {
        customerSignaturePad.clear();
    });
    document.getElementById('clear_image_draw').addEventListener('click', function () {
        imageDrawPad.clear();
        imageDrawCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageDrawCanvas.width, imageDrawCanvas.height);
    });

    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        var employeeSignatureData = employeeSignaturePad.toDataURL();
        var customerSignatureData = customerSignaturePad.toDataURL();
        var imageDrawData = imageDrawPad.toDataURL(); 

        document.getElementById('employee_signature_data').value = employeeSignatureData;
        document.getElementById('customer_signature_data').value = customerSignatureData;
        document.getElementById('image_draw_data').value = imageDrawData;

        if (employeeSignaturePad.isEmpty() || customerSignaturePad.isEmpty() || imageDrawPad.isEmpty()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please provide both signatures and draw on the image.');
        }
    });
};

$(function() {
    var employees = @json(array_map(function($employee) { return $employee['name']; }, $employees));
</script>
```

web.php

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TicketController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;

// Login routes
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

// Authenticated routes
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    // Ticket routes
    Route::get('/', [TicketController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/add-ticket', [TicketController::class, 'create']);
    Route::post('/add-ticket', [TicketController::class, 'store']); 

    // Ticket specific routes
    Route::prefix('ticket')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/{id}', [TicketController::class, 'show']);
        Route::get('/{id}/pdf', [TicketController::class, 'generatePDF']);
        Route::put('/{id}', [TicketController::class, 'updateStatus']);
        Route::put('/{id}/report', [TicketController::class, 'updateReport']);
    });

    // Home route
    Route::get('/home', [TicketController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

TicketController

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Log the request data
    \Log::info('Request data:', $request->all());

    $ticket = new Ticket;
    $ticket->full_name = $request->full_name;
    $ticket->cpr = $request->cpr;
    $ticket->password = $request->password;
    $ticket->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
    $ticket->invoice_no = $request->invoice_no;
    $ticket->products_with_issue = $request->products_with_issue;
    $ticket->issue_description = $request->issue_description;
    $ticket->received_by = $request->received_by;
    $ticket->assigned_to = $request->assigned_to;
    $ticket->employee_signature = $request->employee_signature;
    $ticket->customer_signature = $request->customer_signature;
    $ticket->image_draw = $request->image_draw;
    $ticket->save();

    return redirect('/add-ticket')->with('status', 'Ticket added successfully!');
}
```

Comment: You submit the form, and then add data to elements of the form that has already been submitted. This is too late for the data to be correctly sent with the form submit.

Comment: i update it as what you suggested but it's still the same @Sitethief

Comment: Are you already authenticated, when you are submitting this form - or is your form submission request getting redirected to the login route first, and then you log in, and are getting redirected back to `/add-ticket`?

Comment: the issue is i got this error when submitting the form after i'm logged in
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'employee_signature' cannot be null

it pass signature as '?'

but if i remove auth or i logout it works without issue and it submit the form directly

@CBroe

Comment: so this input is not in the request data?

Comment: The obvious first step here is to look at the contents of the request object. But you aren't doing any validation on the inputs, and why are you not using `new Ticket($request->all());`???